# Pip install works in terminal but packages arent there in Pycharm?

Tags: python, terminal, pip, pycharm

Ok, I'm trying to install various packages like pandas and NumPy in Pycharm, and via Terminal (I'm on a mac), they are installed without issues and I can list them with pip list -

[image]

Then, however, when I go to Pycharm and do an `import`, I get the error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

I tried the Pycharm settings and installing the package there, but then I get-
[image]

What is wrong here?

Interpreter:

[image]

Comment: When you install the package in the Terminal, how have you activate the virtual env? Please show all the steps to recreate.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the wrong interpreter within pycharm when executing the code with the import statement. Check settings > project > project interpreter and make sure that the correct interpreter is selected.

Comment: I selected the interpreter that matches my project - see the edit

Comment: did you install the package in the relevant virtual environment that you have selected as your project interpreter?

Comment: I looked at that - and I just selected the "make new environment" option and selected Python 3.7, but still no luck